# How to change a label color from another ViewController? in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, colors

I have 2 VieControllers(FirstViewConroller & SecondViewController)
I have a label In SecondViewController
And a Button in FirstViewController

I want the label color to change when I click the button

But I don't know how to do it

Comment: Are you using storyboard for the ViewControllers navigation?

Comment: yes my friend..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy way is to pass the color parameter from `FirstViewController` to `SecondViewController`, then update the UI when `SecondViewController` layout its subviews.

You can do it on the `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` method

FirstViewController

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let viewController = segue.destination as? SecondViewController
        viewController?.labelColor = .red
    }

}
```

SecondViewController

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    var labelColor: UIColor?
    @IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        testLabel.backgroundColor = labelColor
    }
}
```

Result:
[image: Colored UILabel]